# Excel: get last date based on value in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've looked for some time and am confused as to how to do this properly. I need to get the lastest a value occured. I have this is two columns

```
Dates   User Ids
01/01/2019  abc10
01/01/2019  rim344
01/01/2019  foo770
01/01/2019  hocpoc
01/01/2019  con587
01/01/2019  chk123
```

Etc, this goes on for thousands of lines, with a total of 300 hundred different User Ids.

Now, I want to get the latest date user abc10 logged in. Preferably presented with the unique set of User Ids rather than the raw data. How the ... do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a pivot table, where 'user_id' is in rows and 'dates' is in values, then go to value field settings (by clicking on 'dates' in the pivot table fields window) and change the setting to 'Max' (instead of the default setting of 'count'). this way you will get a list of all users and their Max ride date
:)

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

The first step is to copy column **B** into column **C**.  Then use the RemoveDuplicates feature in the `Data` tab to get the unique IDs.  Then in **D1** enter the array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(B:B=C1,A:A,""))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Excel supports it (Office 365/Excel 2019), you can use `MAXIFS`:

```
=MAXIFS($A$2:$A$301,$B$2:$B301,"abc10")
```

Alternatively, you can use the following array formula (enter it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=MAX($A$2:$A$301*--($B$2:$B$301="abc10"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a pivot table, it will be more convenient I believe:

[image]

You basically need to select the data, insert a pivot table where you want it to be, put the User Ids under Rows and Dates under Values. Then Change the summurization for values to Max (right click on the values in the pivot table or in the value field settings in the right panel) and format as date.

You will instantly get a list of all users with their respective latest date.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I eventually got this working using the following

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:A17040=E2),B2:B17040)
```